# What is the c program exit(0) equivalent function call in erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

How to kill the erlang program within erlang program? **exit/1** command does not behave same as **c** language standard library **exit** call.

Comment: An Erlang VM is different from a normal C program (or even a Java VM) in that it works like a small operating system. The correct way to stop it is to call init:stop() as Roger noted below. This gives running processes a chance to terminate cleanly, like a Unix "shutdown". An alternative is to call erlang:halt(), but this just stops the Erlang VM immediately, and could cause you to lose data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`init:stop()` (see [init:stop/0, /1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#stop-0)) or `erlang:halt()` (see [erlang:halt/0, /1, /2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#halt-0)) will stop the node immediately.

Comment: init:stop() is usually the correct thing to do. halt() is much more brutal, but might occasionally be what you want.